# Javascript function closures and access to parent scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I have a question about whether or not what I'm attempting is possible in Javascript in regards to closures and parent scopes. Here's my code:

```
var func1 = function() {
    // console.log(this.source1);   // wont work, makes sense
    // console.log(source1);        // wont work, wish it would
    console.log(this.source2);      // works fine
    console.log(source2);           // works fine
};
var func2 = function() {
    var source1 = "source1";
    this.source2 = "source2";
    func1.call(this);
}();
var func3 = function() {
    var source3 = "source3";
    var func4 = function() {
        console.log(source3); // also works fine, makes sense
    }();
}();
```

Is there any way I can get access to variables declared with var on func2 inside func1, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said -- no.

But if you put this whole thing in a wrapper and use the Revealing Module Pattern, then you can.

```
var module = (function() {
    var source1;
    var source2;

    var func1 = function() {
        console.log(source2);           // works fine
    };
    var func2 = function() {
        source1 = "source1";
    }();
    var func3 = function() {
        var func4 = function() {
            console.log(source1); // also works fine, makes sense
        }();
    }();

    return {
      func1: func1,
      func2: func2,
      func3: func3
    };

}());

// Then invoke them.
module.func2();
module.func1();
```

**EDIT**

Then you can re-assign them back to the original names.

```
var func1 = module.func1;
var func2 = module.func2;
var func3 = module.func3;
```

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately, I can't make that kind of rework. Gives me an excuse to wait until arrow functions are available with ECMAScript 6 though, as that will solve my actual issue.

Comment: @dvlsg - See my edit -- might give you something to play with.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no.

The scope of the inner function is limited to its own scope and the scope of the outer function in which the inner function is declared (not called but declared).

`console.log(this.source2);` works fine cause both function have `window` as their context (window plays role of the outer function). `this = window` inside those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, it won't work, and it shouldn't. Thankfully :) That's exactly how local variables are supposed to behave.

One thing you can do is pass the desired variable to the function *func1* (and the function should expect it. Which is no problem — if you wish to somewhere call this function without passing a variable, Javascript would be totally okay with it)

Another thing is to declare the **source1** variable without "var" keyword. Then it would work, but you really shouldn't do that unless you're keeping a very good track of your global variables.